# Can I block certain apps when connected to personal hotspot?

Tags: tethering

Is there any way I can have certain apps like chrome be blocked from internet usage while connected to a personal hotspot to avoid wasting data? I would like to only allow a few apps like Mail and iMessage to use internet while connected to the hotspot. I know there are some paid apps out there like TripMode, but is there any way to do this for free?

Comment: Honestly TripMode is the way to go. I don't think there is any way to do that for free, and TripMode works so well and unobtrusively imho